# How to configure DNS Setting for EMAIL (GoDddy) in AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, godaddy-api

I bought the domain in Bigrock, they pointed in AWS perfectly.
My website is hosted in an AWS EC2 instance, where I created a Virtual machine and used an IIS Server.
I want to use email for this domain. I bought Email Services in GoDaddy. They want me to some configure like TXT, MX, etc. which I can't find in AWS.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You have a DNS record (an `A` record or `CNAME` record) in your DNS service (Bigrock?) that points to the EC2 instance. You now need to go back into your DNS service to create the `TXT` and `MX` records for your email service. The EC2 instance is completely uninvolved in this process.

Comment: Please just go to Bigrock control panel and you can setup your TXT and MX record.